# How to deal with ambiguities in same template multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, class-template

I am working on my own WinAPI wrapper library, which takes care of everything related to GUI. I've kind of ported solutions I saw on Android platform (Views, measure/layout/draw passes, "inflating" UI from XML).

Now: I didn't want to repeat myself and add manually static methods such as create and inflate to each `View` (`Button`, `GridView`, `TextView` etc.).

Base `View` class derives from (passing View as T):

```cpp
template<class T>
class ICreatable : std::enable_shared_from_this<T> {
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<T> create() {
        return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T()); //assume that T has such constructor
    }
    static std::shared_ptr<T> inflate(AttributeSet* attrs) {
        return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(attrs)); //assume that T has such constructor
    }
    std::shared_ptr<T> ptr() {
        return enable_shared_from_this::shared_from_this();
    }
};
```

Child classes derive from View and ICreatable:

```
class Button : public View, public ICreatable<Button> {
    //...
}
```

Now I have to deal somehow with ambiguity - Button has ICreatable with both View and Button passed as T. I would like `Button` to override `ICreatable<View>` with `ICreatable<Button>`.

- Is that even possible in C++?
- If not, is there another way of
  achieving this kind of "automatic static method addition"?
- Should I
  go back to my first (terrible) idea of manually adding static
  create() and inflate() methods to each View?

EDIT:
After a bit of discussion I've made a `#define` way of shortening those methods to one line:

```
#define InsertCreatableMethods(T) \
static std::shared_ptr<T> create() {\
return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T());\
}\
static std::shared_ptr<T> inflate(AttributeSet* attrs) {\
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(attrs));\
}
//...
class Button : public View {
    //...
public:
    InsertCreatableMethods(Button)
    //...
}
```

The code above is the best way of achieving what I want (well, the most lazy way, I think).

Comment: Why do you want the same class to be both ICreatable<View> and ICreatable<Button>? What does that mean? When you want Button::inflate to be called what do you want called ICreatable<View>::inflate or ICreatable<Button>::inflate?

Comment: I want each View class to have only one ICreatable (having "the latest" class as T), but as some Views derive from other ones, the ICreatable is also derived with them.

Comment: No, View is not abstract. Also there are longer "chains of inheritance" here. For example: ICreatable->View->ViewGroup(+ICreatable)->LinearLayout(+ICreatable)

Comment: Why do you need here all the `shared_from_this` stuff?

Comment: I use it... somewhere. Initially it was sitting in View class (and ptr() returned shared_ptr<View> which could be cast dynamically to deriving class...

Answer (score 0):

If you write `IView` as follows:

```
template <class T>
class View : public ICreatable<T>
```

You can the write Button as:

```
template <class T>
class Button : public View<T>
```

And no need for double inheritance.
If you have another

```
class RadioButton : public Button<RadioButton>
```

In general it is not good design to have a deep inheritance tree. Intermediate leaves should be abstract. A `Button` doesn't have a concrete meaning. Only a `RadioButton` does. The better design would look like:

```
template <class T>
class IView : public ICreatable<T>

class View : public IView<View>

template <class T>
class IButton : public IView<T>

class Button : public IButton<Button>
```

This way there is no double inheritance and every class has a straightforward inheritance tree for every class.

Comment: That was my first thought, but right now any `View` can derive from other one, and the benefit of having ViewGroup with ICreatable would be lost if I would like to create `LinearLayout` with another ICreatable. Of course I could create IViewGroup which would have `final ViewGroup` and `ILinearLayout` with `final LinearLayout`

Comment: Have all your class add that small `template <class T>` boilerplate and then your entire structure will work. I think you don't really want multiple inheritance because there is really only one way to create each class.

Comment: Well, I made this ICreatable because I am lazy and I hate to repeat same thing many times (it's a waste of time). And I think that using kind-of-ugly defines for each class would be easier than refactoring everything by adding templates (which should have all the code inside).

Comment: Is using defines in cpp code considered extremely bad, or just bad? ;)

Comment: Templates are usually considered the CPP way of writing defines. And the boilerplate of adding the defines is just as large as the boilerplate of adding the template line.

Comment: And you end up all the library in header files. That would be hell

Comment: It appears also my solution doesn't work. You can't write Button<Button> because it doesn't know what Button is.

Comment: The best way is to have a normal class hierarchy.